# Counter in a function global/static

Tags: php, static, yii

I want that each time I call the function actionNewAnswer, the counter raises.
But now, the counter is always 2. What's wrong?

```
public function actionNewAnswer(){     
    static $count = 1;
    ++$count;

    $modelAntwoorden = $this->loadModelAntwoorden();

    $this->renderPartial('_formAnswer', array(
        'model' => new VraagAntwoord(), 
        'counter' => $count,
        'modelAntwoorden'=>$modelAntwoorden,
    ),false,true);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`actionNewAnswer()` calling only once at one request to server, and next time it's new

1st, add to config

```
'cache' => 'CFileCache'
```

2nd, add const in Controller class

```
const myStaticCount = 'myStaticCount';
```

3rd, add to actionNewAnswer

```
$count = 0; // comment for zero +1
if (Yii::app()->cache->offsetExists(self::myStaticCount)) {
    $count = Yii::app()->cache->get(self::myStaticCount);
}
Yii::app()->cache->set(self::myStaticCount, ++$count);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$count` start at 0 so to go to 1 at first call?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Yes, it is! But Author has some strange logic, maybe it's important :)

Comment: Thanks! Yes the counter with number 1, is generated by another method.